# Websocket nodejs outgoing middleware

Tags: node.js, http, websocket

Is there any tool for capturing outgoing websocket traffic and modifying requests/responses? I need to test the correct behavior of my app that works with an external server with its own API, but I don't want to mock the entire server in order to do so. So what I want is to capture the traffic and make some modifications in both requests and responses in order to test error handling.

Comment: I use [mock-socket](https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket) to test WebSocket in my apps. You don't have to mock all the entire server, only the events that you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

You could always call your own function(s) that in turn forward data to the "real" functions (or even replace the existing functions you're calling).